# Changing the show hide events

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a button "upload a background" when it is clicked the input type="file" is shown. I've done it using jquery .click() and .show() and .hide() and it works. But I want to change the input type="file" back to the button when it is clicked somewhere else in the page. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
Upload<input type="button" id="upload" />
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

css:

```
#file{display:none;}
```

jquery:

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
$('#upload').hide();
$('#file').show();
});
```

How can I change the #file back to #upload when the mouse pointer is clicked somewhere in the page.

EDIT: (is this right?)

```
$("#upload").click(function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    $("#file").show('slow');
    $("#upload").hide();
});

$(document).click(function(){
$('#uploadbg').show('slow');
$('#uploadform').hide();
});
```

Still not working.
Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: please make your question clear or make a demo of what you need here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @coder I updated the question. please check it

Comment: You should not return before executing the code in the function; return has to be the last statement in the function, otherwise the code will never be executed.

Comment: Could you show me the working demo?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function(){
   $('#upload').show();
   $('#file').hide();
});
```

each click that has no it's own handler will trigger document.click because of event bubbling.

Comment: When I clicked outside it does'nt change

Comment: Now the actual click event for the button itself is not working. But thanks. could you change it and show me here http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/GXAYa/36/

Comment: @rnk updated. You have to stopPropagation of the event in your button click handler (or simply return false which stops propagation) so the code does not propagate up to the document's click handler.